# How to extract text from li tag which is again appearing under another li tag in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Below is the HTML of the customized drop down from which I want to select a sub level hierarchy, I am not able to add code so i have attached image of the HTML

```
![This is the image of the HTML of my code in which there are li tags under one li tag and I want to extract text of all li tags][1]


<ul id="selhierarchy" class="mcdropdown_menu" style="position: absolute; top: 604px; left: 486px; display: block; z-index: 999999; visibility: visible; height: 44px;">
<li class="mc_root mc_parent" rel="5" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; width:     297px;">
Key_element1.1
<ul style="display: none; z-index: 999999; top: 27px; left: 0px; visibility: visible; height: 22px;">
<li class="mc_parent mc_endcol" rel="12" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; width: 150px;">
Key_element2.1
<ul style="display: none; z-index: 999999; top: 23px; left: 0px; visibility: visible; height: 22px;">
<li class="mc_endcol" rel="13" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; width: 150px;">Key3.1</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="mc_root mc_parent mc_endcol" rel="6" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; width: 297px;">
Key_element1.2
<ul style="display: none; z-index: 999999; top: 50px; left: 0px; visibility: visible; height: 22px;">
<li class="mc_parent mc_endcol" rel="14" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; width: 150px;">
Key_element2.1
<ul style="display: none; z-index: 999999; top: 23px; left: 0px; visibility: visible; height: 44px;">
<li class="" rel="15" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; width: 150px;">Key3.2</li>
<li class="mc_endcol" rel="16" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; width: 150px;">Key3.1</li>
```

Comment: not able to add the HTML code here

Comment: Are you not able to paste the content in Question area ?

Comment: you can, just indent the code with 4 spaces.

Comment: @HemChe - yes , I am not able to paste it in content are,

Comment: @bagonyi - I did it but it is again showing the validation

Comment: @HemChe and bagonyi - see I had 20 lines of HTML code and it is showing only 2 lines

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.tagname("li")); // Parent element
WebElement we1 = we.findElement(By.tagname("li")); // child element

String arg = we1.getText(); 
System.out.println(arg);
```

Comment: Hi Devendra_Patil; your code might be correct, but with some context it would make a better answer; for example, you could explain how and why this proposed change would resolve the questioner's problem, perhaps including a link to the relevant documentation. That would make it more useful to them, and also more useful to other site readers who are looking for solutions to similar problems.

Comment: **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)